# GCP auth timeout when importing

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am importing 16,000 records from a CSV into Firestore using a simple node script in the GCP CLI.

The CSV has four columns that area each written as a new doc in the collection. I have to process the CSV asynchronously as each row written from the CSV is linked to the data in the previous row. As a result, the import takes 5+ hours.

The process continually fails with the following error:
**Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.**

I suspect that this is because as this is a long async task the auth token is expiring. From what I have read auth tokens have a 1-hour life.

I have simplified my code below to simulate the CVS import issue. When run in the Google Cloud Platform command line this reproduces the error.

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const db = new Firestore();
var previous = '';

async function processRecord(record) {
    console.log(record);
    console.log(record);
    let collectionRef = db.collection('groups');
    const snapshot = await collectionRef.where('name', '==', 'World').get();
    let data = {
        name: record,
        previous: previous,
        created: Firestore.Timestamp.now()
    }
    let docRef = await db.collection('testing').add(data);
    previous = docRef.id;
}

async function importCsv(csvFileName) {
    var records = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 16000; i++) {
        records.push(`Filler: ${i}`);
    }

    // const fileContents = await readFile(csvFileName, 'utf8');
    // const records = await parse(fileContents, { columns: true });

    for (const record of records) {
        await processRecord(record);
    }
    console.log(`Processed ${records.length} records`);
}

importCsv(process.argv[2]).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

What can I do to allow my import to complete?

Comment: Are you logged in? You could try allowing public access so you don't need to pass the token.

Comment: I am logged into the Google Cloud Platform. How do I allow public access?

Comment: You can enable anonymous sign in in firebase. I have only done this with firebase functions so I'm not sure it works in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED: Modified the whole answer after more details were given (code example and a better description of the requirements)**

The best way to avoid the errors due to an auth token expired is to do the load quicker (5 hours for 16k is way too much time). This can be achieved in many ways, but after reviewing the code provided I created two nodejs scripts that can fulfill your needs of creating a "reversal linked list" without taking more than 1 minute to load the whole set of 16k records.

**Explanation:** Creating a record and reading it in the same transaction is an slow approach, it's better to create the records and then query the full data set and update accordingly. Also it's highly recommended to use batches for the writing and updating operations because the server side library does parallelized individual writes, more information about this can be found in the next link: [Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes):

> For bulk data entry, use a server client library with parallelized individual writes. Batched writes perform better than serialized writes but not better than parallel writes. You should use a server client library for bulk data operations and not a mobile/web SDK.

**Script:** The first part is to load the whole data set, I used the dummy load provided on your code to exemplify this, however you can replace the records variable with the loaded rows from your csv file. Also please note that I use a numeric index to fill the `previous` field, this is important to keep tracking on the order that we loaded the records.

**batch_writing.js**

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();
async function batch_writting() {
    var records = [];
    let writeBatch = firestore.batch();

    for(var i = 0; i < 17000; i++) {
        records.push(`Filler: ${i}`);
    }
    let index = 0;
    for (const record of records) {
        let documentRef = firestore.collection('testing').doc();
        let data = {
            name: record,
            previous: index,
            created: Firestore.Timestamp.now()
        }
        writeBatch.create(documentRef,data);
        if((index+1) % 500 === 0){
            writeBatch.commit().then(() => {
                console.log('Successfully executed batch.');
            }).catch(e => console.error(e));
            writeBatch = firestore.batch();
        }
        index++;
    }
    writeBatch.commit().then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully executed batch.');
    }).catch(e => console.error(e));
}

batch_writting().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

After the writing part is done and the `previous` field is populated with an incrementing index, we can then proceed to query the full recently created dataset and proceed to update the `previous` key with the correct *Document ID* from the previous row loaded. This is done by ordering the query by the `previous` field, that was populated with in incremental index. Please note that the first record will have a numeric value of 0 due to it not having a previous loaded row.

**update_writing.js**

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();
async function batch_update(){
    let query = firestore.collection('testing');
    query.orderBy('previous', 'asc').get().then(querySnapshot => {
        let writeBatch = firestore.batch();
        let previousID = 0;
        let index = 0;
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
            writeBatch.update(documentSnapshot.ref,{previous: previousID})
            previousID = documentSnapshot.id;
            if((index+1) % 500 === 0){
                writeBatch.commit().then(() => {
                    console.log('Successfully executed batch.');
                }).catch(e => console.error(e));
                writeBatch = firestore.batch();
            }
            index++;
        });
        writeBatch.commit().then(() => {
            console.log('Successfully executed batch.');
        }).catch(e => console.error(e));
    });
}

batch_update().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

If you need to query more fields or another collections, feel free to change the scripts, but remember to avoid querying an specific field and favor the queries that gather the full data set. Also if you need additional writes favor the use of batch writings.

Comment: Yes, using a modified similar tutorial. The difference is this for loop is not async whereas when I upload, each record needs values from the prev record so I have to do my for loop async. This is why the auth times out as the loop will take 5+ hours to complete.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question and include the code for the import part, specially if you're making also queries to the collections, because this is not mentioned in any part of the question and is relevant for the answer

Comment: I edited my whole answer to do a better job at boarding the questions and code provided by the post

Comment: @Dercni have you tried to import with the code provided?

Comment: your code worked well for the scenario I described so I have ticked it, thank you. Unfortunately, this was a simplified version of my scenario and the file still needs to be processed sequentially. As Firestore cannot use refresh tokens there appears to be no way to perform a long async task such as this.